# How to create a CoffeeScript style existential operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

CoffeeScript turns `user?.id` into

```
if (typeof user !== "undefined" && user !== null) {
   user.id;
}
```

Is it possible to create a JavaScript function `exists` that would do something similar? i.e.

```
exists(user).id
```

would result in either `user.id` or `null`

It would be easier if a function accepts another parameter, i.e. `exists(user, 'id')`, but that wouldn't look as nice.

Comment: For this one would need general purpose getters (`definegetter(o, function(property){...})`, which are, if I recall correclty, not part of JavaScript's specification.

Comment: @Zeta Not really, since accessing a nonexistent property of an object returns `undefined` instead of failing, which should be good enough.

Comment: The closest I can think of is `function exists(obj) { if (obj) return obj; return {}; }`, but that won't handle undefined variables. Javascript isn't syntactically extensible that way.

Comment: You'd have an issue with `user` being not defined (different from having the value `undefined`), where that won't have the same behaviour.  You could just declare something like `var user;` for the sake of it, then it'd be fine but it creates quite a bit of clutter.

Comment: Checkout the lodash get function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't produce such a function. The problem is that this:

```
any_function(undeclared_variable)
```

will produce a ReferenceError if `undeclared_variable` was not declared anywhere. For example, if you run this stand alone code:

```
function f() { }
f(pancakes);
```

you'll get a ReferenceError because `pancakes` was not declared anywhere. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wSZaL/

However, the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) can be used on something that has not been declared so this:

```
console.log(typeof pancakes);
```

will simply log an `undefined` in the console. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/et2Nv/

If you don't mind possible ReferenceErrors then you already have the necessary function in your question:

```
function exists(obj, key) {
    if (typeof obj !== "undefined" && obj !== null)
        return obj[key];
    return null; // Maybe you'd want undefined instead
}
```

or, since you don't need to be able to use `typeof` on undeclared variables here, you can simplify it down to:

```
function exists(obj, key) {
    if(obj != null)
      return obj[key];
    return null;
}
```

Note the change to `!=`, `undefined == null` is true even though `undefined === null` is not.

Answer (score 2):

Very old question but made me thinking about this solution.

```
exists = (obj) => obj || {}
exists(nullableObject).propName;
```

Comment: nope. To quote coffeescript.org: "It’s a little difficult to check for the existence of a variable in JavaScript. if (variable) … comes close, but fails for zero, the empty string, and false (to name just the most common cases)"

Answer (score 0):

I think this functional approach might be interesting **until optional chaining is included in JavaScript** [(State 1 of TC39)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining):

Using proxies and a [`Maybe`](https://medium.com/@yyankowski/maybe-monad-in-javascript-to-save-us-from-the-hell-of-the-null-guard-clauses-bc9f9a1f291b) monad, you can implement optional chaining with default value return in case of failure.

A `wrap()` function is used to wrap objects on which you want to apply optional chaining. Internally, `wrap` creates a Proxy around your object and manages missing values using a `Maybe` wrapper.

At the end of the chain, you unwrap the value by chaining `getOrElse(default)` with a default value which is returned when the chain is not valid:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: [4, 1, 2]
  },
  c: () => 'yes'
};

console.log(wrap(obj).a.getOrElse(null)) // returns 1
console.log(wrap(obj).a.b.c.d.e.f.getOrElse(null)) // returns null
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([])) // returns [4, 1, 2]
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[0].getOrElse(null)) // returns 4
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[100].getOrElse(-1)) // returns -1
console.log(wrap(obj).c.getOrElse(() => 'no')()) // returns 'yes'
console.log(wrap(obj).d.getOrElse(() => 'no')()) // returns 'no'

wrap(obj).noArray.getOrElse([1]).forEach(v => console.log(v)) // Shows 1
wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([]).forEach(v => console.log(v)) // Shows 4, 1, 2
```

The complete example:

```js
class Maybe {
  constructor(value) {
    this.__value = value;
  }
  static of(value){
    if (value instanceof Maybe) return value;
    return new Maybe(value);
  }
  getOrElse(elseVal) {
    return this.isNothing() ? elseVal : this.__value;
  }
  isNothing() {
    return this.__value === null || this.__value === undefined;
  }
  map(fn) {  
    return this.isNothing()
      ? Maybe.of(null)
      : Maybe.of(fn(this.__value));
  }
}

function wrap(obj) {
  function fix(object, property) {
    const value = object[property];
    return typeof value === 'function' ? value.bind(object) : value;
  }
  return new Proxy(Maybe.of(obj), {
    get: function(target, property) {
      if (property in target) {
          return fix(target, property);
      } else {
        return wrap(target.map(val => fix(val, property)));
      }
    }
  });
}

const obj = { a: 1, b: { c: [4, 1, 2] }, c: () => 'yes' };

console.log(wrap(obj).a.getOrElse(null))
console.log(wrap(obj).a.b.c.d.e.f.getOrElse(null))
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([]))
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[0].getOrElse(null))
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[100].getOrElse(-1))
console.log(wrap(obj).c.getOrElse(() => 'no')())
console.log(wrap(obj).d.getOrElse(() => 'no')())

wrap(obj).noArray.getOrElse([1]).forEach(v => console.log(v)) // Shows 1
wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([]).forEach(v => console.log(v)) // Shows 4, 1, 2
```