# Optional Chaining in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

I've been programming a lot in Swift recently. Today I did some work in JavaScipt when question popped up to me:

Is there something similar to optional chaining in JavaScript? A way to prevent `undefined is not an object` without any variables?

Example:

```
function test(){
   if(new Date() % 2){
      return {value: function(){/*code*/}};
   }
} 

test().value();
```

will fail half of time because sometimes `test` returns undefined.

The only solution I can think of is a function:

```
function oc(object, key){
   if(object){
      return object[key]();
   }
}

oc(test(), 'value');
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
test()?.value()
```

The part after the question mark is only executed if `test` returned an object.

But this is not very elegeant. Is there something better? A magic combination of operators?

**Edit** I know I could rewrite `test` to return something. But I'm wondering if there's something like optional chaining. I'm not interested in a particular solution to the above *example*. Something that I also can use if have no control over the function returning undefined.

Comment: what you want value() to return when test() return undefined?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed false or undefined. It does not matter really.

Comment: you can wrap the existing function to return a default value in the case of undefined, without rewriting. you can also use a ternary (x?y:z)() or default operator (x||y)() at call-time.

Comment: @dandavis But that would me require to write a wrapper function for each function I want to call. And what should I return in this functions? (Look at my 2nd example)

Comment: i was thinking you could use the same wrapper on each one you wanted to default, even with little more than an array of function names and one map(), but maybe i don't understand the goal. functions are very malable in JS, so it should not take repetition or boilerplate. RE: edit, "(x=test()) && x.value()" is shorter than a wrapper, or if you get back a truthy instead of an object sometimes, (x=test()) && x.value && x.value(); but a re-usable function that operates on functions would leave behind cleaner code.

Comment: Not possible in JS, but you can simplify the [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/0p49xpj5/) using `&&`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I was just wondering if there is something like optional chaining in JavaScript because JS is full of surprises.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is currently a Stage 4 proposal you can check on the progress of it here:
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

You can use the babel plugin today:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining

**Update 11th January 2020:**
Babel now supports optional chaining by default
https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/01/11/7.8.0

The Optional Chaining operator is spelled `?.`. It may appear in three positions:

```
obj?.prop       // optional static property access
obj?.[expr]     // optional dynamic property access
func?.(...args) // optional function or method call
```

**Notes:**

In order to allow `foo?.3:0` to be parsed as `foo ? .3 : 0` (as required for backward compatibility), a simple lookahead is added at the level of the lexical grammar, so that the sequence of characters `?.` is not interpreted as a single token in that situation (the `?.` token must not be immediately followed by a decimal digit).

Also worth checking out:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing

https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 7):

In plain JavaScript you have to do type checks or structure your code so that you know an object will exist.

CoffeeScript, a language that compiles down to JavaScript, provides an existential operator `?.` for safe chaining if you're willing to consider a preprocessed language.

There's another discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341456/how-to-create-a-coffeescript-style-existential-operator-in-javascript) about why you can't reproduce this behavior in JS.

There is also a discussion [on the ESDiscuss forums](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/the-existential-operator) about adding an existential operator to a future version of JavaScript.  It doesn't seem very far along though, certainly nowhere close to practical use.  More of an idea at this point.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it really answers my question unlike the other answers below and because it provides some interesting information.

Answer (score 5):

Optional chaining has landed in JS. We can use optional chaining via the `?.` operator in object property access. It allows us to try accessing properties of objects which might not exists (i.e. are `undefined`) without throwing an error.

Here is a code example:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: 1
  }
};

// If we try to access property which doesn't exists
// it just returns undefined
console.log(obj.baz);

try {
  // Now we try to access a property of undefined which throws an error
  obj.baz.foz;
} catch (e) {
  console.dir(e.message);
}

// Now we use the optional chaining operator ?.
// We get undefined instead of an error
console.log(obj.baz?.foz);
            
console.log(obj.foo?.bar);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
test() && test().value();
```

or

```
var testResult = test();
testResult && testResult.value();
```

If you ask me this is most similar to Swift's optional chaining.

Comment: `test() && test().value()` is inappropriate if `test` has side-effects or if `test` returns a falsy value other than `null` or `undefined`, and of course it still fails if `test()` doesn’t have a `value` property, or its `value` property isn’t a function.

Answer (score 3):

Optional Chaining is finally in the JavaScript standard!

Here are a few examples:

```
// properties
foo?.bar
foo?.bar()
foo?.bar.baz()
foo?.bar?.baz()

// indexing
foo?.[0]
foo?.['bar']

// check if a function is defined before invoking
foo?.()
foo.bar?.()
foo?.bar?.()
```

And this is way better than what most people use for manually checking for nulls

Instead of evaluating

```
foo?.bar
```

to this little code snippet we are all used to writing

```
foo ? foo.bar : null
```

it actually evaluates to

```
foo == null ? undefined : foo.bar
```

which works for all the falsey values like an empty string, 0 or false.

---

Unrelated to the question, but you might also be interested in the `??` operator.

It has a similar purpose as `||` except it only checks for null or undefined.

For example:

```
foo ?? bar
```

would be the same as:

```
foo != null ? foo : bar
```

---

This is a very new feature, so even thought a lot of users already use a browser that supports this you will still want to use a tool to convert it to an older version of javascript.

Answer (score 2):

`var Obj = {Prop: {name: 'peter'}}`

`console.log(Obj.Prop.name)
 console.log(Obj?.Prop?.name)`

In the first sentence, you're just accessing object properties. The problem with that is that if you find `Prop` to be something other than an object, it will throw an exception. That's the reason of the [optional chainig operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Lets say you try to do `Obj.Prop2.name`.
You'll get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`
if Instead you did `Obj.Prop2?.name`, You'll only receive `undefined` as a value, instead of an exception.

This is particularly useful when accessing deeply nested properties.

WARNING: This is a relatively new JS feature that's not yet implemented in all browsers, so be careful while using it for production applications.

Answer (score 0):

What about returning a noop function that does nothing when the condition isn't met?

```
function test(){
   if(new Date() % 2){
      return {value: function(){/*code*/}};
   }
   return {value: function(){ /* just return a type consistent with the function above */ }
}
```

Comment: This was just an example. I'm talking about functions I don't have control about.

Comment: gotcha. sorry. You need something like the `?.` operator in Groovy. There's no such thing in JS.

Comment: @sebnukem - there is a proposal for that operator now - see my answer