# What does this conditional statement do?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm working on some javascript legacy code and I came across this conditional, can anyone tell me what does the '?' do? The 'items' property is not part of the currentItem object and it never is...

```
if (currentItem?.items)
```

Comment: The optional chaining means that there won’t be an error “can’t read items of undefined”if currentItem is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Optional Chaining in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183944/optional-chaining-in-javascript)

---

That's the optional chaining operator.

> The optional chaining operator (?.) permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid.

Read more: [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (MDN)