# Question mark after parameter as in obj.val?.prop

Tags: javascript

I met in code condition line like this `someObject.arrParam?.length`. What syntax is that? How does that question mark thing's called? I know an **optional operator** which used for parameters in functions. Is that a variation of usage of it? Never met before.

Comment: Perhaps => [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Duplicate of [Optional Chaining in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183944/optional-chaining-in-javascript). See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is called **Optional Chaining** in JavaScript.  It allows to drill
> down on objects without raising null exception.

Eg: Try running the below code snippet, then uncomment the line and run it to understand a working example.

```js
let employeeA ={ name: "Dane", address : { city:"London"}}
let employeeB ={ name: "John"}

console.log(employeeA.address.city)
// console.log(employeeB.address.city) <----  this will raise an error
console.log(employeeB.address?.city) // <--- this wont
```

This was introduced as new feature in the latest ESNext iterations.

NodeJS Support : https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----

Current Browser Support : https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining

More Details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 3):

That is called [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (or conditional chaining) which basically will evaluate the whole expression as `undefined` if `arrParam` is `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score -3):

It's called "[Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)".

`result=condition?ifTrue:ifFalse`

In `x=(y>10)?100:1`, if y>10, x is set to 100, else, x is set to 1.

Equivalent to:

```
if(y>10) x=100;
else     x=  1;
```

Comment: No, that’s not it.