# Getting the Data from API to be able to display in the app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, expo

I am facing an issue of displaying the information that i retrieved from the API. When i tried to display the information, i get the following error above. I have used two useeffect react hook one is to get the classid from the DynamoDB table based on the parameters i have provided when the page loads and another is to get the list of subjects based on the classid.

```
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Calendar} from 'react-native-calendars';
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
import React, { useEffect,useCallback,useRef,useState } from 'react'


const HomePage = () => {
  //use for navigating/redirect to other page
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const handleUserIconClick = () => {
    //navigate to setting page
    navigation.navigate('Profile');
  };
  const [classid,setclassid] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => { // Get the class id from the child table based on the guardianID 
    getData("7b11614e-a7eb-4223-bdf4-0ece9b634eb2")
},[])// <- this means it only run once

  useEffect(() => { // Get the subjects from the class table based on the classid
    getSubjects(classid)
},[classid]) // <- this means it will run once the classid changes

  
  const getData = async (GID) => {
    try {
      const apiData = await API.get('api55db091d', '/child/getclassid',{queryStringParameters:{
        GID:GID
      }})
      setclassid(apiData.data[0].ClassID)
      console.log("Here getData",apiData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const getSubjects = async (classid) => {
    console.log("getsubjects ClassID",classid)
    try {
      const apiData = await API.get('api55db091d', '/class/getsubjects',{queryStringParameters:{
        ClassID:classid
      }})
      setData(oldArray => [...oldArray, apiData]);
      console.log("Here getSubjects",apiData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.background}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.topRight} onPress={handleUserIconClick}>
            <Ionicons name="person-outline" size={35} color="#FFFFFF" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>Timetable:</Text>
            <ScrollView horizontal={true} contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContent}>
            {
              data.map(data1 => {            
                return (
                  <View style={[styles.card, styles.cardElevated]}key={data1.ID}>
                  <Text style={styles.classText}>Subject: {data1.Subject}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.classText}>Day: {data1.Day}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.classText}>{data1.StartTime} - {data1.EndTime}</Text>
                </View>
                )
                
            })} 
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>Calendar:</Text>
          <View style={styles.calendar}>
          <Calendar  style={styles.calendartest}/>
      </View>
    
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#B3EAE5',
  },
  topLeft: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: height * 0.08,
    left: width * 0.05,
  },
  topRight: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: height * 0.07,
    right: width * 0.05,
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  card: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: width * 0.65,
    height: height * 0.16,
    width: width * 0.60,
    height: height * 0.15,
    borderRadius: 4,
    margin: width * 0.05,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  cardElevated: {
    elevation: 4,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
    },
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    paddingTop: height * 0.15,
  },
  absentContainer: {
    paddingTop: height * 0.07,
  },
  welcomeText: {
    fontSize: height * 0.03,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: height * 0.025,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    //marginBottom: height * 0.01,
    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.05,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  classText: {
    fontSize: height * 0.018,
    color: '#1DC1B1',
  },
  scrollContent: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  endClassButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: height * 0.05,
    right: width * 0.03,
    width: width * 0.2,
    height: width * 0.14,
    borderRadius: width * 0.1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  endClassText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: height * 0.01,
    right: width * 0.03,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: height * 0.024,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
  },

  calendar:{
    paddingTop: height * 0.02,
    alignItems:'center',
  },
});
export default HomePage;
```

I have tried many ways but could not figure that what went wrong. I am expecting to be able to display the data that i have gotten from the API into the app.

[Here is the error that i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwlJT.jpg)

[Here is just some tracking to determine what is going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU8YB.jpg)

Comment: I have provided my code above and this is what i have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that maybe you miss something like having classId as a dependency on the second use effect hook, if you want help please share some of your code.

After back and forth with the user we solved the issue, it was just a miss setStatement from the backend since his backend has data in the response.

I would advise to check this:
[Some helpful keywords and general expressions in js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9550412/10233327)

but specifically this since it's in your code now:
[?. explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63722672/10233327)

given your style of code maybe lodash get method would help you:
[lodash get](https://medium.com/crocusenergy/how-i-started-to-use-lodash-in-the-front-end-react-js-e465caaa45eb)

vs code has a nice extension called prettier, please for the love of god format your code. I always have it format on save to get rid of the hassle.

[pretter extension for vs code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Comment: does your console.log("Here getSubjects",apiData) work?

Comment: Yes it works i have send a screenshot of it but i have a feeling that the usestate data is not updated and when the data.map tried to display,it has nothing to display

Comment: by your api logic, shouldn't it be, data.data.map ?

Comment: no i tried it say "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: it does that because you setData as empty array at first, so data.data does not exist, it should work with data?.data?.map

Comment: I am sorry but i am confused so i just edit the .map function ?

Comment: yes. data?.data?.map instead of data.map that you have right now

Comment: I tried and it solved the issue but not displaying the info for example data1.Subject,data1.Day etc

Comment: can you just return an empty view 
<View><Text> I am just a random entry</Text></View>

Comment: i tried but the empty view is not displaying

Comment: it must be the way you set your array then, can you do setData(apiData) instead of 
setData(oldArray => [...oldArray, apiData]);

Comment: i tried and yes it is working

Comment: Alright, I will update my original answer for some helpful things for you.

Comment: thanks you so much. but anyway may i know what i did wrong so that i am able to learn. Still new to react native