# Conditional chaining in JS false if not found

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In JS's optional chaining (I don't think it's implemented in current versions), can I have it evaluate to false if not found?

```
var obj = {a: {foo: "bar"}}
console.log(obj.a?.foo); //bar
console.log(obj.b?.foo); //this is undefined, I want it to be false
```

I read [Optional Chaining in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183944/optional-chaining-in-javascript) and [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015) but neither answered my question.

Comment: Have you tried ? `console.log(obj.b?.foo !== undefined)`

Comment: What does this have to do with jsx? There's no jsx syntax in your question

Comment: Are you looking for `obj.b?.foo ?? false`?

Comment: @Bergi yeah thats exactly what i needed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!!` or `!= null` (pay attention != not !== to check both undefined and null)

```js
var obj = {a: {foo: "bar"}};
console.log(!!obj.b?.foo);
console.log(obj.b?.foo != null);
```