# What does ?. operator mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form and I came across ?. operator. What does it mean?
Here is some context on how it's used

```
<span>{errors?.name?.message}</span>
```

Where errors is destructured from useForm() like so

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
```

Here is a full form input to paint a clearer picture

```
<input 
   type="text" 
   id='name' 
   name='name'
   {...register('name', {
      required: {
        value: true,
        message: 'Name cannot be empty'
      }
    })}
    placeholder='John Doe' 
    className='px-6 w-full rounded-md py-2 text-gray-700 focus:outline-none' 
                    
   />
<span>{errors?.name?.message}</span>
```

Comment: It is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional Chaining in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183944/optional-chaining-in-javascript)

Comment: it means the property is `optional` or can potentially be `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?.` is the optional chaining operator. Here is the MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

For example if you run the below code, you will face an error

```js
a = {}
console.log(a.b.c)
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined`

But if you do not want to add a try-catch, but it is acceptable for that value to be absent, then you can do the following

```js
a = {}
console.log(a.b?.c)
```

This will result in `undefined` to be printed to the console. The error in accessing c is silently handled.